# Powershell pass criteria to Out-GridView

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to run `Out-GridView` with pre-defined criteria?
I have three columns:
Computer, Source Role and Assignee.

Basically, I'm searching by Computers to see which access group (Assignee column) will give access to the server, but often we're getting requests to give access to many servers at once.

So I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image: Out-GridView image]

But without the need to specify it manually in the GridView.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Why not filter the object before running Out-Gridview?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could use this approach. 
Just remove all items from the array that are not matching.